# Hibernate JPA fetch joins should not be used in paged queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In the [Hibernate User Guide chapter 15.14](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join) it says:

> Fetch joins should not be used in paged queries (e.g. setFirstResult()
> or setMaxResults()), nor should they be used with the scroll() or
> iterate() features.

There is no further explanation why JPQL queries like this one:

```
List<Person> persons = entityManager.createQuery(
    "select distinct pr " +
    "from Person pr " +
    "left join fetch pr.phones ", Person.class )
.setFirstResult(15)
.setMaxResults(10)
.getResultList();
```

should be avoided.

Can someone explain what are the rationales behind this interdiction?

**UPDATE**

I found out [this post](https://vladmihalcea.com/query-pagination-jpa-hibernate/) that explains everything.

**UPDATE 2**

To be more precise:

1. Why it is forbidden for 1-1 lazy relationships since no row can be lost?
2. Why it is not implemented with 2 selects behind the scene? (
   Something like:

   ```
    select pr.id from Person pr where ... pagination
    select distinct pr from Person pr left join fetch pr.phones where pr.id in (:ids_from_previous_select)
   ```

)

Comment: you got any exception ?

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya No, this is an approach issue, more like an anti-pattern.

Comment: Check this comprehensive post, specially the **join fetch** part https://vladmihalcea.com/query-pagination-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: @Aman Thanks, but it is the same link I did provide in the update section.

Answer (score 5):

This is because if use `JOIN` and apply limit offset directly to the SQL, you will end up with possibly truncated list of related entities.

Eg if we will have `Person` with `Friends` and will take first 5 records (first page, 5 items of size) you wil end up with 1 person with 5 frends where in fact, you wated to have 5 persons with all friends.

To overcome that, hiberante will execute whole query without limit and will apply limit/offset after aggregation. This will make eg iterable cursor not iterable at all.

```
HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!
```

Comment: That means it will fetch all data from databse and apply limit/offset in the application side which cost huge memory and time.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is why it is not suitable for pagination.

Comment: The same thing applied to OneToOne case also? I didn't test it. Personally I avoid it and use projection most of the time.

Comment: No, 1-1 relations are eagarly fetched unless specified otherwise. Also 1-1 relations will produce exactly the same number of rows.

Comment: Okay, I mean make OneToOne Lazy and just want to join fetch when I want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not forbidden for one-to-one associations, that's totally fine. It's just problematic for collections i.e. *-to-many associations.

I think Hibernate could be adapted to do fetch joins more efficiently when doing pagination, but it just isn't implemented this way.

I did implement the kind of pagination you mention for Blaze-Persistence which is a library that works on top of JPA/Hibernate: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#pagination

There are even a few further optimizations in there:

- Only the necessary joins are done in what I call the "id-query"
- The id query does not necessarily have to be a separate query. In fact, by default, Blaze-Persistence inlines this query into the "object-query"
- Blaze-Persistence also supports the much more efficient keyset pagination through the same API